# Python DLL load failed, whilst having installed packages

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to run a python script however I get the message

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing.
```

Full  error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ROC_plotting.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
    import FixTk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 68, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is geen geldige Win32-toepassing.
```

It seems some of these errors are concerning Matplotlib, however when I run

```
pip list
```

It seems that I do have installed matplotlib

pip list output:

```
cycler (0.10.0)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
matplotlib (2.0.2)
numpy (1.11.3+mkl)
opencv-python (2.4.13.2)
pip (9.0.1)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
python-dateutil (2.6.0)
pytz (2017.2)
scikit-learn (0.18.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

My python version is 2.7.13, I'm running on a 64-bit Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not your python version, make sure you have Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 64bit installed as it's used by matplotlib check in Control Panel > Programs